# S3 as Target Dir in Sqoop Import

Tags: amazon-s3, sqoop

Trying to import database table using sqoop import command with target directory specified as Amazon S3 bucket name.
The command is as below

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/mytable --username myuser --password mypassword --table mytable --target-dir s3://<secret_code>:<secret_key>@s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/
```

It keeps giving me Access Denied S3Exception. The secret key/code credentials are valid and bucket permissions are set for everyone.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, Are you able to access to target directory using hadoop command fro your console: hadoop fs -ls s3://<secret_code>:<secret_key>@s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/

Comment: Nope. Same error. Can it be related with special characters in secret key ? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you don't have access to target directory. Please check if the url is correct.

Comment: i tried the same credentials with distcp and works very well. guess, i will have to do it in two steps. first, import into hdfs using sqoop and then copy from hdfs to s3 using distcp

Answer (score 0):

did you try out this below link? it should be s3a as per the blog.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_sqoop_s3_import.html

```
sqoop -Dfs.s3a.access.key=xxxxx -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=xxxxx -Dfs.s3a.endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com" \
import --connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/mytable --username myuser --password mypassword --table mytable \
--target-dir s3a://mybucket/
```