# ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import: when importing Mysql data into S3

Tags: mysql, linux, sqoop, incremental-linking

I am trying to import mysql data into s3 bucket using the following command through sqoop

```
sqoop job --create myJob -- import -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true -Dfs.s3a.access.key=<ACCESS_KEY> -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=<SECRET> --connect jdbc:mysql://<IP>:3306/<DB> --username root --password root --table <TABLE_NAME> --target-dir s3a://<BUCKET>/<NAME> --as-avrodatafile --compress --incremental lastmodified --check-column <COLUMN_NAME> -m 1 --append
```

And I am getting the following error

```
 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -Dfs.s3a.access.key=
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --connect
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/xxxxx
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --username
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: xxxx
2021-06-27 04:32:45,858 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --password
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: xxxx
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: xxxxxx
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: s3a://xxxxx/xxxxxx
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --as-avrodatafile
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --compress
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --incremental
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: lastmodified
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --check-column
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: xxxxxx
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -m
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 1
2021-06-27 04:32:45,860 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --append
```

I can't find what's the issue for getting this issue since i am a novice user of sqoop.

Comment: Check Out Old similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583153/s3-as-target-dir-in-sqoop-import